# Delete rows if some cells are empty in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I can delete rows that have empty cells in a specific field, I used the following query but did not work :(

```
DELETE `my.table` WHERE TC = NULL or HDL = NULL or TG = NULL or LDL = NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `IS` instead of `=`

```
DELETE `my.table` 
WHERE TC IS NULL or HDL IS NULL or TG IS NULL or LDL IS NULL
```

or you can use

```
DELETE `my.table` 
WHERE TC || HDL || TG || LDL IS NULL
```

Comment: U know Mikhail, I should acknowledge you upon publication of my research, would you allow me to do so?

Comment: sure. no problem

Comment: so did it work for you?